# How to resolve error on Stripe xamarin binding? (CS0103 The name 'Start' does not exist in the current context)

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, stripe-payments

I'm trying to make a new binding for the Stripe Android SDK, because the bindings out there are outdated and lacks the SCA authentication, a new feature released recently that will be required in EU markets.

Stripe Information: https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android
Stripe repository: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android

I'm using the last version available today, the 10.2.1, and I have only one error left:

> Error CS0103  The name 'Start' does not exist in the current context

I have some experience making bindings for Android but this one is hard to resolve:

If I go to the autogenerated class where the error is reported -PaymentAuthWebViewStarter- I can see this:

```
    // This method is explicitly implemented as a member of an instantiated Com.Stripe.Android.View.IAuthActivityStarter
    void global::Com.Stripe.Android.View.IAuthActivityStarter.Start (global::Java.Lang.Object p0)
    {
        Start (global::Java.Interop.JavaObjectExtensions.JavaCast<global::Com.Stripe.Android.PaymentAuthWebViewStarter.Data>(p0));
    }
```

But there is no code for Start there. It is expected because the api.xml show me the following code for that class:

```
<class abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" extends="java.lang.Object" extends-generic-aware="java.lang.Object" jni-extends="Ljava/lang/Object;" final="false" name="PaymentAuthWebViewStarter" static="false" visibility="public" jni-signature="Lcom/stripe/android/PaymentAuthWebViewStarter;">
  <implements name="com.stripe.android.view.AuthActivityStarter" name-generic-aware="com.stripe.android.view.AuthActivityStarter&lt;com.stripe.android.PaymentAuthWebViewStarter.Data&gt;" jni-type="Lcom/stripe/android/view/AuthActivityStarter&lt;Lcom/stripe/android/PaymentAuthWebViewStarter$Data;&gt;;">
  </implements>
  <field deprecated="not deprecated" final="true" name="EXTRA_AUTH_URL" jni-signature="Ljava/lang/String;" static="true" transient="false" type="java.lang.String" type-generic-aware="java.lang.String" value="&quot;auth_url&quot;" visibility="public" volatile="false">
  </field>
  <field deprecated="not deprecated" final="true" name="EXTRA_CLIENT_SECRET" jni-signature="Ljava/lang/String;" static="true" transient="false" type="java.lang.String" type-generic-aware="java.lang.String" value="&quot;client_secret&quot;" visibility="public" volatile="false">
  </field>
  <field deprecated="not deprecated" final="true" name="EXTRA_RETURN_URL" jni-signature="Ljava/lang/String;" static="true" transient="false" type="java.lang.String" type-generic-aware="java.lang.String" value="&quot;return_url&quot;" visibility="public" volatile="false">
  </field>
  <field deprecated="not deprecated" final="true" name="EXTRA_UI_CUSTOMIZATION" jni-signature="Ljava/lang/String;" static="true" transient="false" type="java.lang.String" type-generic-aware="java.lang.String" value="&quot;ui_customization&quot;" visibility="public" volatile="false">
  </field>
</class>
```

As you can see, there is no trace of any Start method. the interface is declared and have the Start method signature as expected, like this:

```
<interface abstract="true" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="AuthActivityStarter" static="false" visibility="public" jni-signature="Lcom/stripe/android/view/AuthActivityStarter;">
  <typeParameters>
    <typeParameter name="StartDataType" classBound="java.lang.Object" jni-classBound="Ljava/lang/Object;"></typeParameter>
  </typeParameters>
  <method abstract="true" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="start" jni-signature="(Ljava/lang/Object;)V" bridge="false" native="false" return="void" jni-return="V" static="false" synchronized="false" synthetic="false" visibility="public">
    <parameter name="p0" type="StartDataType" jni-type="TStartDataType;">
    </parameter>
  </method>
</interface>
```

On the other hand, if I look into the .aar classes using JD-GUI (java decompiler) I can see that the Start is defined in the PaymentAuthWebViewStarter class:

```
  public void start(@NonNull Data data)
  {
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("client_secret", data.mClientSecret);
    extras.putString("auth_url", data.mUrl);
    extras.putString("return_url", data.mReturnUrl);
    extras.putParcelable("ui_customization", this.mToolbarCustomization);

    this.mHost.startActivityForResult(PaymentAuthWebViewActivity.class, extras, this.mRequestCode);
  }
```

My questions are:

Why this method is not being generated as any other method in any other class?

How to resolve this issue?

I've left my code here: https://github.com/guillermo-gerard/stripe.android.sdk.binding/tree/master
You are more than welcome to fork it and try to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after struggling a little more, I'll fix my problem, but I'm not sure yet why it was happening in the first place.

The changes are already published in the repo, but just in case it helps to anyone: I have to add a partial class in Additions to implement the call to the missing member, like this:

```
namespace Com.Stripe.Android
{
// This class fixes the  Error CS0103  The name 'Start' does not exist in the current context
public partial class PaymentAuthWebViewStarter : global::Java.Lang.Object
{
    internal new static readonly JniPeerMembers _members1 = new XAPeerMembers("com/stripe/android/PaymentAuthWebViewStarter", typeof(PaymentAuthWebViewStarter));

    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.stripe.android']/class[@name='PaymentAuthWebViewStarter']/method[@name='start' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='com.stripe.android.PaymentAuthWebViewStarter.Data']]"
    [Register("start", "(Lcom/stripe/android/PaymentAuthWebViewStarter$Data;)V",
        "GetStart_Lcom_stripe_android_PaymentAuthWebViewStarter_Data_Handler")]
    public virtual unsafe void Start(global::Com.Stripe.Android.PaymentAuthWebViewStarter.Data data)
    {
        const string __id = "start.(Lcom/stripe/android/PaymentAuthWebViewStarter$Data;)V";
        try
        {
            JniArgumentValue* __args = stackalloc JniArgumentValue[1];
            __args[0] = new JniArgumentValue(
                (data == null) ? IntPtr.Zero : ((global::Java.Lang.Object) data).Handle);
            _members1.InstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod(__id, this, __args);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
}
}
```

And that's it, this resolves the compilation problem and I've been able to generate the dll.
After including it in the project, new errors appear, but they are resolved now.

Disclaimer: I DID NOT fully tested the binding yet, I'm only sure that it can be included in a project and that the credit card information can be entered using the stripes widget. I didn't test the SCA behavior nor the 3DS authentication yet. So if you are going to use this binding please test it fully and let me know if anything goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to create a binding for iOS?

Comment: Hi Paulo, not for the moment, sadly. I don't need the iOS binding for this project.

Comment: Did it work ok? Are you using Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Droid?

Comment: Hi, paulo, until now it is working just fine. I'm not using forms for this project